# Capture d’écran 2019-06-18 à 18.26.40.png

Tags: spyder

With the code shown hereunder, spyder 3.3.4 return the following error message :

```
AttributeError : module 'random' has no attribute 'randit'
```

The code is as follows:

```
import random, math
SV = 0 #somme des valeurs du temps d'attente
SC = 0 # somme des carrés du temps d'attente
nb_simul = 5000 #nb simulations
for k in range(nb_simul):
    arr1 = random.randit(0 , 60) #arrivée 1
    arr2 = random.randit(0 , 60) #arrivée 2
    c = abs(arr1 - arr2)#tps d'attente
    SV = SV + c
    SC = SC + c*c
MV = SV / nb_simul#moyenne des temps d'attente
MC = SC / nb_simul#moyenne des carrés des temps d'attente
e = sqrt((MC - MV*MV)/nb_simul) #écart-type des moyennes des temps 
d'attente
print("Estimation ponctuelle :", MV)                
print("Intervalle de confiance à 95% [", MV - 1.96*e, ";", MV + 
1.96*e,"]" )
```

Comment: `Capture d’écran 2019-06-18 à 18.26.40.png` is probably an image, not a question itself. Please edit your post

Comment: Thanks ! The problem is solved, it consisted in an error of writing : randit instead of randint.